# How to combine three tables data to retrieve a data

Tags: sql

I have the below three tables & its column and want a data as below

```
Sensor  - SystemID,Sensorname, Sensortime    
User  - EmpID,SystemID    
Incident  -IncID,EmpID,DateOpened,Description
```

I want to retrieve the sensor data(from Sensor Table) for the EmpID which had Incident.Description field contains  word 'System' and Sensor.Sensortime falls 4 days prior to the Incident.DateOpened

Please guide how do I combine these three tables and get this data

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: try joining them on basetable.PK = childtable.FK (where PK and FK is common column in both table). You will get example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH two_tables AS(
SELECT * FROM Sensor s JOIN User u
ON s.SystemID = u.SystemID) t
SELECT * FROM Incident i JOIN two_tables on i.EmpID = t.EmpID
```

This is a rough sketch, you can build on this. Please, try sharing the sql attempt so it can be easier.